# Z3Py Constants with user defined sorts different by default

Tags: z3, z3py

I have an uninterpreted sort Dataset:

```
Dataset = z3.DeclareSort("Dataset")
```

When I create constants from this sort:

```
d = z3.FreshConst(ZDataset)
d2 = z3.FreshConst(ZDataset)
```

I want the solver to see them as different, so `d == d2` should be unsat.

Is there any way to do this by default, so every time I create a constant, it is different from all others already made?

The most straightforward solution I can see is to create a mock uninterpreted function like:

```
mock = Function(
    "mock", ZDataset, z3.IntSort()
)
```

and each time I create a constant, add a constraint to the solver:

```
solver.add(mock(d) == 0)
```

using a Python variable that is incremented each time.

Although it is not the cleanest solution, it makes the solver see them as different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mock` function you're talking about is probably the easiest way to do this cleanly.

Another way would be to do:

```py
solver.add(Distinct([d, d2, d3, ...]))
```

right before you call `check`. You need to do this for all such objects you created, so you might want to keep track of them in some sort of a list as they are created.

I don't think either solution is fundamentally better/worse from a performance perspective, though `Distinct` might be better as the solver understands it natively and thus might make some internal simplifications kick in earlier. It'd be best to experiment.